# Контент одного сайта в другом сайте

Tags: python-3.x, css3, html5, flask

Небольшая предыстория:
У заказчика есть сайт который глубоко не в топе. Заказчик планирует наплодить лендингов с хитрым перенаправлением трафика с лендингов на основной сайт что бы поднять основной сайт в топе поисковиков.

Есть ли возможность решить вот такую задачу:
Есть основной сайт собранный на битриксе (если это имеет значение), на сайте есть галерея с фотографиями. Так же, на Flask **будут написаны** лендинги, у каждого из них будет своя (пустая) галерея.

Задача:
Необходимо что бы на лендингах отображалась галерея основного сайта, и при этом трафик с лендингов шел на основной сайт... сложность в том что бы не использовать JS и/или PHP.

Это должно быть что-то в роде фрейма, только отображаться в нем должна именно галерея не вся страница целиком, ну и без JS и PHP, только HTML, CSS, Python...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А в чем проблема на лендингах натыкать все ссылки на основной сайт и с основного же тянуть картинки?

Если нужен именно фрейм, то имеет смысл на основном сайте сделать простую страничку-информер с галереей и минимумом js/php (отдавать готовую с сервера, и всё), а ее уже совать во фрейм. Вот только гугл как это поймет, так сразу загонит сайт заказчика в задницу, и будет прав.

Comment: В общем решил просто редирект настроить и не париться)